# OrderBy date in json column of table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-json

One of the columns in my table is array_object. The input of this column is json. In this json there are two variables name and date. Now I want to sort the rows of this table based on the closest date from today onwards. It is important to note that the year is always fixed. Actually, I want to sort by the nearest month and day.

Given that today is 2023-06-11. I want to specify the dates closest to today regardless of the year. My inputs and outputs are as follows
input = 2023-04-22, 2023-06-21, 2023-10-11, 2023-05-29

output respectively =  2023-06-21, 2023-06-21,  2023-04-22, 2023-05-29

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
$ooo = ContentListItem::orderByRaw("ABS(DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(array_object, '$.date')), '\"%m-%d\"'), '" . Carbon::now()->format('m-d') . "'))")
            ->get();
```

The output of this code is as follows, which is wrong :
2023-04-22, 2023-06-21, 2023-05-29 ,2023-10-11,

When I modified the code as below, my output is not repeated and it only performs the sorting for this year and does not consider the data for the following years, but the result is correct until the end of this year.

```
 $ooo = ContentListItem::where('array_object->date', '>=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('array_object->date', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

output =  2023-06-21, 2023-06-21

How can I modify my code to get the desired output?

Comment: When you want to search or order by a field inside JSON, it is better to have it as a separate column in the table.  Then we can talk about how to wrap dates around.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question, my advice to you is that in this case you should use a separate table in which there is a multiple morph relationship that contains the date, name, and any other data.

It will be better in performance, organization, and easier to modify and expand in the future

In the event that you want to use JSON in the search, you can make an alias for the column you want to search with.

```
Model::selectRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.date") AS dataDate')->orderByRaw('CAST(dataDate AS DATE) ASC');
```

for more details.

[link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/order-by-date-in-json-column)